# div positioning right under the other inline

Tags: html, css

can someone please tell me why the 3rd div is looking that way instead of being right under the 1st div? And what would I need to write in my CSS file to make the 3rd div positioned right under the 1st one?
[image]

This is the HTML:

```html
<div class="div-main">
  <div class="div-1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="div-2">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="div-3">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```css
.div-main {
  border: 5px solid yellow;
  padding: 15px;
}

.div-1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30vh;
  display: inline-block;
}

.div-2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 69%;
  height: 50vh;
  display: inline-block;
}

.div-3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30vh;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why this is happening?

By default, the [`block` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout/Block_and_Inline_Layout_in_Normal_Flow), whether they are `block` or `inline-block`, will fill all the available space in the row, so if the blocks should have an overlapping situation, you can't achieve it with `block` approaches.

## How to solve it?

With the [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) approach, you can make sure how each element should be positioned in your box. You can specify how your columns should be distributed by using the [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns), and how your rows should do it, with the [`grid-auto-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows) property. You can also ensure how much of your current available space should be filled with the children by using [`grid-column`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column) and [`grid-row`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row) on each child.

The grid approach:

```css
.div-main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}

.div-1, .div-2, .div-3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.div-1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.div-2 {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.div-3 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-main">
  <div class="div-1">1</div>
  <div class="div-2">2</div>
  <div class="div-3">3</div>
</div>
```

### How the above code works?

In this example by default,

- I distributed the available space for the column into 3 even blocks (`grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)`).
- I set the minimum of each row to be `100px` and allow them to grow if other blocks in the container want them to (`grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto)`).
- At last, I set the children to fill the available space the way I wanted (`grid-column: *;` `grid-row: *;`).

**NOTE1:** If in any case you want to make the third child gets bigger in height in comparison to the second child you can change the second part of `grid-row: 2 / 3;` to a bigger number like `grid-row: 2 / 4;`.

```css
.div-main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}

.div-1, .div-2, .div-3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.div-1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.div-2 {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.div-3 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-main">
  <div class="div-1">1</div>
  <div class="div-2">2</div>
  <div class="div-3">3</div>
</div>
```

**NOTE2:** You can learn more about how CSS `grid` works in the [CSS-tricks website](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) with more examples.

Comment: Good explanation set here so +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

Here I don't directly say why; I think others have done a great job there. Here I show how you can place items in columns in a container, and then forced some sizing to show the effect of doing that within individual blocks - and why sizing to the containing element might be more desirable at times.

I added a left/right block to illustrate the effect of creating logical groups of elements to work with by simply wrapping them in a `group-left` and `group-right` thus if you change `grid-template-columns: minmax(150px, 30%) 30%;` to `grid-template-columns: minmax(150px, 30%) 1fr;` the right group takes up whatever is remaining - a typical left/right layout where you have say links in the left group for example.

The only difference between the to major containers here is the content of each and those styles added to those contained elements.

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(150px, 30%) 30%;
}

.group-left {
  border: solid purple 3px;
  background-color: #77008822;
}

.group-left>* {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.group-right {
  border: solid orange 3px;
}

.content-block {
  /* just here to center the text in both directions */
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}


/* below here is now just color and border styling and some forced sizing */

.div-main {
  border: 5px solid yellow;
  /* padding: 15px;*/
}

.div-1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* force a height */
  height: 30vh;
}

.div-2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* force a height */
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: #eeffdd;
  /* this can make the second block wider and potentially overlap the next column */
  width: 20em;
}

.div-3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* force a height */
  height: 30vh;
}

.forced-height {
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: #44ddff33;
}

.img-force {
  border: dashed 2px cyan;
  width: 50%;
  height: 30vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent div-main">
  <div class="group-left">
    <div class="content-block div-1">1 is a happy one
    </div>
    <div class="content-block div-2">
      2 here
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group-right">
    <div class="content-block div-3">
      3 is not sad
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="group-left">
    <div class="content-block">1 is a happy one
    </div>
    <div class="content-block forced-height">
      2 here
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group-right">
    <div class="content-block">
      <img class="img-force" src="" alt="no soup for you"> 3 is not sad
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inline elements can't position themselves like what you want as they're block level elements. You can use CSS grid and set div-2 to span two rows. There's a lot to grid but it's really flexible. Have a look. I've annotated the CSS so you can see how I've done it.

Some good resources on [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) and here's a [video](https://youtu.be/rg7Fvvl3taU) by Kevin Powell that's a handy introduction.

```css
.div-main {
  border: 5px solid yellow;
  padding: 15px;
  /* this makes a grid layout with 2 columns and as many rows as needed. */
  /* There's only 3 divs so that'll automatically give us 2 rows */
  /* The grid-template-columns property is the width of each column - though there are some qualifications with this */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 69%;
}

.div-main>div {
  /* I've moved this to its own rule so you don't need to repeat yourself */
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
}

.div-1 {
  /* I've kept the height of your original divs */
  height: 30vh;
}

.div-2 {
  height: 50vh;
  /* setting grid-row: span 2 makes this div use two rows when it's being displayed */
  /* this allows the third div to appear to the left */
  /* in effect there's 4 cells in this grid but the last, bottom right cell is taken up by div-2 as we've told it to span 2 rows */
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.div-3 {
  height: 30vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-main">
  <div class="div-1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="div-2">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="div-3">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```